# Using contact cleaner for keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware, repair

I used contact cleaner to keyboard for my MBP 2020 and after that I learnt that it was a mistake. There is no problem except oily buttons for now. But I'm really scared that my computer will malfunction anytime. What should I do?

I promise I will use air spray next time.

Answer (score -1):

It depends what precisely was in the contact cleaner.
Good modern ones shouldn't leave any noticeable residue, but old ones [& really cheap ones] will leave greasy residue & also rot the plastic, making it brittle & eventually crumble.

Not really sure what to suggest next - but your choices are

1. Hope & pray.
2. Take it to an Apple service centre or Store.

Comment: Thanks. I will take it to the service. Hope they don't cancel the guarantee.

Comment: I guess the downvoter never used Servisol [which was *the* industry standard] back in the 80s & before, with its clear warning "Do not allow overspray onto plastics". I once ignored that & the casing literally fell apart in my hands after 6 weeks.

Comment: I used a spray that can be used on plastics and it's going well now.